# "C/C++: ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries" ERROR

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

i am debugging my android app on windows and its working but its giving errors when i wanna make a build.

I changed my versions but it is not changing anything.

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[armeabi-v7a] FAILED
> C/C++: ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

> Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a] FAILED
> C/C++: ninja: error: manifest 'build.ninja' still dirty after 100 tries

> Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED

[error pic is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08URZ.png)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue, I am also getting same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yep also confirmed the problem goes away when you move the project to a directory with a shorter absolute file path. I've spent an unnecessary amount of time trying to find other workarounds involving CMake and ninja configuration and none of it made any difference. Ultimately it seems like an issue with ninja and Windows rather than anything specific to this project